# Printing numbers in reverse right angle triangle

Tags: python, python-3.x

Define a function named `print_mirrored_right_angle_reverse_pattern(number_of_rows)` which takes an integer as a parameter and prints a specific right angle triangle using numbers. The numbers should be in reverse order. Note: you may assume that the number of rows will always be > 1 and < 10.

This is how the output should be,

---

[image]

Following is the code I have written so far

```
def print_mirrored_right_angle_reverse_pattern(number_of_rows):
    for i in range(1,number_of_rows+1):
        print(" "*(number_of_rows-i), end='')
        for j in range(i):
            print(i, end='')
        print()
```

Please help me get the correct output

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def print_mirrored_right_angle_reverse_pattern(number_of_rows):
    for i in range(1,number_of_rows+1):
        print(" "*(number_of_rows-i), end='')
        for j in range(i,0,-1):
            print(j, end='')
        print()

print_mirrored_right_angle_reverse_pattern(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this code:

```
def print_mirrored_right_angle_reverse_pattern(number_of_rows):
  for i in range(1, number_of_rows+1):
    total = ""
    print(" "*(number_of_rows-i), end='')
    for j in range(1, i+1):
      total = str(j) + total
    print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this. You just need to run the for loop backwards.

```
for j in range(i,0,-1):
    print(j, end='')
```